# Консольный ввод/вывод C#

Tags: c#

Есть задачи не знаю как решать, делать на C#(часть с обменом значений естественно понятно, неясно как остальную часть)

1. Очень часто нам необходимо поменять местами два числовых значения. Программа просит пользователя ввести 2 числовые переменные. А после она меняет их местами и выводит результат на экран. Но, так как пользователь может ошибиться, необходимо предусмотреть тот факт, что пользователь может ввести, например, букву или строку, а так же учесть, что число может быть дробным, и для выделения её дробной части одни используют точку, другие – запятую.
2. Программа для подсчета периметра и площади фигур (треугольник, четырехугольник, круг). Пользователь выбирает фигуру, указывает, что программа будет считать – площадь или периметр. Задаётся все необходимые значения,  а на основе полученных результатов, программа должна подсчитать, какими могли бы быть периметры или площади остальных фигур.

Comment: И что непонятного, где ваш пример кода?

Comment: 1) Для проверки можно использовать TryParse нужного типа; точки-запятые можно решить с указанием нужной "культуры": [system.decimal.tryparse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8). 2) "а на основе полученных результатов, программа должна подсчитать, какими могли бы быть периметры или площади остальных фигур" - вот это как понимать?

Comment: @XelaNimed я думаю во второй задаче имелось ввиду поиск периметра или площади от выбранного типа фигуры. Там достаточно использование switch-case и написания пару методов...

Comment: В том-то и вопрос: для площади и окружности круга хватит радиуса, для треугольника нужно либо длину всех сторон, либо угол и длину прилежащих к нему сторон, а для четырёхугольника совсем другое. К примеру я выбрал треугольник и его площадь - программа должна показать площадь 3 кругов? Автор должен уточнить вопрос.

Comment: напишите просто решение если нетрудно, сам попросту не в состоянии пробовал решить первую,но всё до чего дошёл это метод tryparse и пробовал его результат в цикле while зациклить и в нём уже выдавать сообщение мол какой формат ввода приемлем что надо точка или запятая для отделения или же сказать мол ввели букву

Comment: говорили мол фигуры считать правильными и треугольник равносторонним чтобы решалось хоть как-то

Comment: Вторая задача - это набивший оскомину пример на наследование: базовый классы `Shape` и его наследники-фигуры. Примеров кода в тырнете - море.

Comment: Если вы знаете как решить задачу -- не стоит писать о ней в вопросе. Чем короче условие, чем меньше лишних подробностей -- тем лучше вопрос. А вот ваш код как раз был бы полезен и уместен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Loop();
    }


    static void Loop()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("For task 1 => press 1 ");
        Console.WriteLine("For task 2 => press 2 ");


        var line = Console.ReadLine();
        int choice;
        if (int.TryParse(line, out choice) == false)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("wrong data input, try again input only digits");
            Loop();
        }
        else
        {
            Tasks(choice);
        }      
    }

    static void Tasks(int choice)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("you choosed Task :{0}", choice));
                Task1();                 
            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("you choosed Task :{0}", choice));
                Task2();
                var line = Console.ReadLine();
                Loop();
            }
                break;
            default:
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("something wrong...");
                var line = Console.ReadLine();
                Loop();
            }
                break;
        }
    }

    static void Task1()
    {
        /*Очень часто нам необходимо поменять местами два числовых значения.
         * Программа просит пользователя ввести 2 числовые переменные.
         * А после она меняет их местами и выводит результат на экран.
         * Но, так как пользователь может ошибиться, необходимо предусмотреть тот факт, что пользователь может ввести, например,
         * букву или строку, а так же учесть, что число может быть дробным,
         * и для выделения её дробной части одни используют точку, другие – запятую.*/
        Console.Clear();
        int a=0,  b=0;
        bool ba = false, bb=false, ba1=false, bb1=false;
        double a1 = 0, b1 = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Task1 enter two digits");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Enter first digit=> ");
        string firstdigit = Console.ReadLine();

        if (firstdigit != null && firstdigit.Contains(",") || firstdigit != null && firstdigit.Contains(".")) // дроби
        {
            if (firstdigit.Contains("."))
            {
                firstdigit = firstdigit.Replace(',', '.');
            }
            if (double.TryParse(firstdigit, out a1))// дробь
            {
                a1 = Convert.ToDouble(firstdigit);

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("first number you enterd is : {0}",a1));

                ba1 = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong data input!!! try again");
                Console.Write("press any key...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Task1();
            }
        }
        else// простые числа
        {
            if (int.TryParse(firstdigit, out a))//простое число
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("first number you enterd is : {0}", a));
                ba = true;
            }
            else// это не простое число
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong data input!!! try again");
                Console.Write("press any key...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Task1();
            }
        }


        Console.Write("Enter second digit=> ");
        string secondigit = Console.ReadLine();

        if (secondigit != null && secondigit.Contains(",") || secondigit != null && secondigit.Contains(".")) // дроби
        {
            if (secondigit.Contains("."))
            {
                secondigit = secondigit.Replace(',', '.');
            }
            if (double.TryParse(secondigit, out b1))// дробь
            {
                b1 = Convert.ToDouble(secondigit);
               Console.WriteLine(string.Format("first number you enterd is :  {0}", b1));
                bb1 = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong data input!!! try again");
                Console.Write("press any key...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Task1();
            }
        }
        else// простые числа
        {
            if (int.TryParse(secondigit, out b))//простое число
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("first number you enterd is : {0}", b));
                bb = true;
            }
            else// это не простое число
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong data input!!! try again");
                Console.Write("press any key...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Task1();
            }
        }
        if (ba && bb)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result : {0} {1}",b,a));
        }
        if (ba1 && bb1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result : {0} {1}", b1, a1));
        }
        if (ba && bb1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result : {0} {1}", b1, a));
        }
        if (ba1 && bb)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result : {0} {1}", b, a1));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("if you want to enter numbers again => press 1 ");
        Console.WriteLine("return to main => press 2 ");
        var line = Console.ReadLine();
        int choice;
        if (int.TryParse(line, out choice) == false)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("wrong data input, try again input only digits");
            Loop();
        }
        else
        {
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                Task1();
            }
            else
            {
                Loop();
            }
        } 








    }

    static void Task2()
    {
        /*Программа для подсчета периметра и площади фигур (треугольник, четырехугольник, круг).
         * Пользователь выбирает фигуру, указывает, что программа будет считать – площадь или периметр. 
         * Задаётся все необходимые значения, а на основе полученных результатов, программа должна подсчитать, 
         * какими могли бы быть периметры или площади остальных фигур.*/
        Console.WriteLine("Task2 choose a figure for calculations");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("for a triangle 1 => press 1 ");
        Console.WriteLine("for circle 2 => press 2 ");
        Console.WriteLine("for for quadrangle 3 => press 3 ");

        var line = Console.ReadLine();
        int choice2;
        if (int.TryParse(line, out choice2) == false)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("wrong data input, try again input only digits");
            Loop();
        }
        else
        {
            switch (choice2)
            {
                case 1://тригольник
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("you choosed triangle ");
                    Console.WriteLine("");

                    Console.WriteLine("to calculate the area => press 1 ");
                    Console.WriteLine("to count the perimeter => press 2 ");

                    if (int.TryParse(line, out choice2) == false)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("wrong data input, try again input only digits");
                        Task2();
                    }

                    switch (choice2)
                    {
                        case 1: 
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Area=1/2*a*h");
                            Console.Write("enter a=> ");
                            var a = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.Write("enter h=> ");
                            var h = Console.ReadLine();
                            double result = 0.5 * Convert.ToDouble(a) * Convert.ToDouble(h);

                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Area=1/2*{0}*{1}={2}", a, h, result));

                            //тут должна считатся плошадь
                        }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                        {
                          Console.WriteLine("perimetr=a+b+c");
                            Console.Write("enter a=> ");
                            var a = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.Write("enter b=> ");
                            var b = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.Write("enter c=> ");
                            var c = Console.ReadLine();

                            double result = Convert.ToDouble(a) + Convert.ToDouble(b) + Convert.ToDouble(c);

                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Perimetr={0}+{1}+{2}={3}",a,b,c,result));
                            //тут должен считатся периметр
                        }
                            break;
                    }

                }
                    break;
                case 2://круг
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("you choosed circle ");
                    Console.WriteLine("");

                    Console.WriteLine("to calculate the area => press 1 ");
                    Console.WriteLine("to count the perimeter => press 2 ");

                    if (int.TryParse(line, out choice2) == false)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("wrong data input, try again input only digits");
                        Task2();
                    }

                    switch (choice2)
                    {
                        case 1:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Area=Pir^2");
                            Console.Write("enter Radius=> ");
                            var R = Console.ReadLine();

                            double result = Math.PI * Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(R), 2);

                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Perimetr=3.14*{0}^2={1}", R, result));

                            //тут должна считатся плошадь
                        }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("perimetr=2PiR");
                            Console.Write("enter Radius=> ");
                            var R = Console.ReadLine();

                            double result = 2 * Math.PI * Convert.ToDouble(R);

                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Perimetr=2*3.14*{0}={1}",R, result));

                            //тут должен считатся периметр
                        }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                    break;
                case 3://четырехугольник
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("you choosed quadrangle ");
                    Console.WriteLine("");

                    Console.WriteLine("to calculate the area => press 1 ");
                    Console.WriteLine("to count the perimeter => press 2 ");

                    if (int.TryParse(line, out choice2) == false)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("wrong data input, try again input only digits");
                        Task2();
                    }

                    switch (choice2)
                    {
                        case 1:
                        {
                            //тут должна считатся плошадь
                        }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                        {
                            //тут должен считатся периметр
                        }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                    break;
                default:
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("something wrong...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                    break;
            }
        }  






    }

}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100001/discussion-on-answer-by-oxygen----c).